# Vuejs + Element UI :How to multiple el-message-box__content

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I am trying to create messageBox that has multiple messagege-box__content like this image.
How can I do this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand it correctly - I mean there are always situations where you might want to do that - but I have a feeling that it might be better to use the Dialog in this case. This gives you more freedom to edit the html unlike the messageBox.

The messageBox looks like [sweetalert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/).

Quote from the docs:

> By design MessageBox provides simulations of system's alert, confirm and prompt，so it's content should be simple. For more complicated contents, please use Dialog.

An example of messageBox usage:

```js
this.$confirm('This will permanently delete the file. Continue?', 'Warning', {
  confirmButtonText: 'OK',
  cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
  type: 'warning'
}).then(() => {
  this.$message({
    type: 'success',
    message: 'Delete completed'
  });
}).catch(() => {
  this.$message({
    type: 'info',
    message: 'Delete canceled'
  });          
});
```

An example of the Dialog usage:

```
<template>
<div>
<el-button type="text" @click="dialogVisible = true" v-text="Open Dialog" />
<el-dialog
  title="I am a dialog"
  :visible.sync="dialogVisible"
  width="50%">
  <span>You could play with the html here</span>
  <p v-for="message in messages" v-html="message" />
</el-dialog>
</div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        dialogVisible: false,
        messages: ["Message one", "Second message"]
      };
    }
  };
</script>
```